# Access modules' props dynamically from root store mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I know I can access a module's state from a mutation in the root store like this:

`state.moduleName.moduleStateProp`

But is it also possible to access `moduleName` dynamically?
I thought of having a shared mutation in the root store which gets committed from actions in different modules. The root store mutation then dynamically mutates the state property of the modules' state which committed the mutation.
I read that there's a `context` object available in an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions) and I tried retrieving the current module's scoped state from there.

That's what I've tried:
Assume I have store modules `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` with a state and action like this:

```
const state = {
  moduleProp: null, // named like this in both modules
};

const actions = {
  someAsyncAction({ state, commit }) {
    axios.get('/my/api/url/')
      .then(res => {
        const payload = {'context': state, 'data': res.data};
        commit('someMutation', payload);
      });
};
```

And a shared mutation in root store like this

```
mutations: {
  someMutation(state, payload) {

    // Do something with payload.data
    
    // Then assign mutated payload.data to module state prop
    state.payload.context.moduleProp = payload.data; // A
  },
}
```

When trying it like this I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')` in the root store on line A.

Question:
Is it at all possible to retrieve the name of the module that committed the mutation? If not, why shouldn't it be possible?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error is that because there is no `payload` property in state object. Mutations doesn't really serve a good purpose and supposed to be eliminated in next Vuex version. You could just change the state in an action and make the thing less convoluted

Comment: Ok I see. I always thought you should differentiate between actions as asynchronous logic and mutations as synchronous tasks which mutate the state.
I get your point with the `payload` prop though. To be sure that I'm not missing something: There is no object that I could access in the root store to retrieve the module name which committed the mutation?

Comment: No, at least in public access. You don't need to infer module name, just pass as a  param